# How to validate a json document/string against an OpenAPI 3.0 schema in yaml with $refs using networknt/json-schema-validator?

Tags: json, yaml, json-schema-validator

My problem is similar to this question:
[How to validate against an OpenAPI schema with $refs using json-schema-validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613113/how-to-validate-against-an-openapi-schema-with-refs-using-json-schema-validator/75978827#75978827)

**Sample Yaml Schema in json:**

```
    {
        "openapi": "3.0.0",
        "info": {
            "title": "API",
            "description": "This API",
            "version": "3.x"
        },
        "servers": [{
            "url": "https://api.yourcompanyexample.com/oi",
            "description": "Example server for your company"
        }],
        "security": [{
            "bearerAuth": []
        }],
        "tags": [{
            "name": "Orders"
        }],
        "components": {
            "schemas": {
                "Order": {
                    "required": [
                        "recipient",
                    ],
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "recipient": {
                            "maxLength": 20,
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Recipient",
                            "example": "Joe"
                        }
                        "customerInformation": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CustomerInformation"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CustomerInformation": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "firstName": {
                            "maxLength": 25,
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Customer’s first name"
                        },
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "maxLength": 254,
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Email address of the customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sample JSON String**

```
    {
        "id": "DemoId",
        "orderId": "DemoOrderId",
        "customerInformation": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "emailAddress": [{
                "emailName": "personal",
                "emailAddress": "evensteven@personal.com"
            }, {
                "emailName": "work",
                "emailAddress": "evensteven@work.com"
            }]
        }
    }
```

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
this.yamlReader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

JsonSchemaFactory this.factory = JsonSchemaFactory.builder(JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4)).objectMapper(yamlReader).addMetaSchema(myJsonMetaSchema).build();

JsonSchema = this.jsonSchema = factory.getSchema(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.yaml"));

JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json"));

**Set<ValidationMessage> errors = jsonSchema.validate(jsonNode); 
// I get no errors even though recipient is missing**

JsonSchema portionSchema = factory.getSchema(jsonSchema.getSchemaNode().get("components").get("schemas").get("Order"));

// I remove customer: $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer' from the schema otherwise it complains about not finding it as it is not loaded in the portionSchema anymore

****Set<ValidationMessage> errors = portionSchema.validate(jsonNode);
//I get error message about the required field**
```

I have also tried loading the schema from "schemas" & "components" node as well. It does not give any error.

**My expectation is:**

JsonSchema portionSchema = factory.getSchema(jsonSchema.getSchemaNode().get("components");
****Set errors = portionSchema.validate(jsonNode);
it should give validation errors.